# How to add cronjobs to /etc/cron.daily/

Tags: cron, cron.daily

- We have to use **crontab -e** to add a cronjob to crontab.
- And **crontab -r** to remove cronjobs.
- Here, **no Copy & Paste not allowed**.

I need to add a script to **cron.daily**, how to add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just drop an executable file (shell script or otherwise) in that folder and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: what about alice?

Answer (score 1):

Just place the script into the cron.daily directory; use cp to copy it from wherever it is to start with.

If you need script adding a line to an existing file the easiest way is

```
echo "Line to add" >> /path/to/file.txt
```

Which will append the new line to the end of the file.